# GCP port 80 connection refused issue: <IP Address> refused to connect

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On my gcp, I have a web app hosted and on `netstat -tupln` i obtain the result as follows:

`tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      21559/docker-proxy`

Here is how my gcp firewall rules look like:
[image]

Even though I have allowed ingressing to `tcp: 80` when I try to land on to the `<ip address>` it gives the following message:
`<IP Address> refused to connect.`

when I ping the ip address like this:
`ping <IP Address>` from my local system, it receives the response as shown below:

```
Reply from <IP Address>: bytes=32 time=259ms TTL=52
Reply from <IP Address>: bytes=32 time=258ms TTL=52
Reply from <IP Address>: bytes=32 time=259ms TTL=52
Reply from <IP Address>: bytes=32 time=259ms TTL=52
```

Can somebody point me where are things going wrong?

**Edit 01: Just found that :80 is actually working. And so reconfigured Nginx port to redirect into the same. Thank you for the patience.**

Answer (score 0):

Just found that IP Address:80 is actually working. And so reconfigured Nginx port to redirect into the same. Thank you for the patience.

**Edit 1: Thank you for the suggestions in comments. Did this modification in `nginx.conf` file: **

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    ...
}
```

to

```
server {
    listen      80;
    ...
}
```

Comment: To make your answer more interesting/valuable, show the changes that you made to solve the problem.